# Can I say パソコンを買いに秋葉原へ行った?

Tags: grammar, word-order

> 秋葉原へパソコンを買いに行った。
>
> パソコンを買いに秋葉原へ行った。

I think both are OK.

Recently I saw someone write "You can't insert anything between 買いに and 行く". Is that true?

Comment: Someone as in...? A trusted source? Or just some person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sound fine to me, too.

[初級を教える人のための日本語文法ハンドブック](https://books.google.co.jp/books/about/%E5%88%9D%E7%B4%9A%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC.html?id=l-C4H2sBJlEC) does say that unlike `[V dictionary form]-ために`, `[V ます-stem]-に` sounds unnatural when something is inserted between it and the main verb.

> ○ 昼食を食べるために出かけた。
>
> ○ 昼食を食べに出かけた。

> ○ 昼食を食べるためにわざわざ出かけた。
>
> ？ 昼食を食べにわざわざ出かけた。

According to the book, this is because `[V1 ます-stem]-にV2` is seen as one sequence of closely associated actions.

However, I don’t particularly find the last sentence to be strange. Even the following sentence sounds acceptable to me (although punctuation could be improved).

> 昼食を食べに友達と一緒にわざわざ秋葉原まで出かけた。

`[N]-に` would sound a bit awkward, especially when the inserted phrase is long.

> ？ 昼食にわざわざ出かけた。
>
> ？ 昼食に友達と一緒にわざわざ秋葉原まで出かけた。

---

[Reference]

◆「〜ために」はＰが移動動作の場合や、使用を表す動詞の場合にも用いることができるので、「〜しに」「〜のに」との違いが問題になります。

(5) 昼食を｛食べるために／食べに｝出かけた。

(6) この網は魚を｛焼くために／焼くのに｝使っている。

両者の違いは、「〜しに」「〜のに」の場合、ＰとＱの間に他の要素が入ると不自然になる点です。これは、「ＰしにＱ」「ＰのにＱ」では、ＰとＱが密接に結びついたひとつなぎの動作のように扱われるためです。

(5)’ 昼食を｛○食べるために／？食べに｝わざわざ出かけた。

(6)’ この網は魚を｛○焼くために／？焼くのに｝母が毎日使っている。

（初級を教える人のための日本語文法ハンドブック §23. 復文と接続詞(3) - 理由・目的 - p216）

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are perfectly fine. You can even use two に and say パソコンを買いに秋葉原に行った.